# How to use Times for operator font with mtpro2 math font?

Tags: fonts, mtpro, times

I am using `mtpro2` math font, and it seems that it automatically (and compulsorily) uses `Computer Modern` for operator fonts. I think this is strange because `mtpro2` is a Times-styled font.

Anyway, how can I use Times for operator font with `mtpro2` math font?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mtpro2}\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=20pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
$\sin$ abcde $a+b$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that the `times` package is obsolete, have a look at `mathptmx`, `helvet` (option scaled=.9), or the `courier` package instead.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have tried many packages (including all the ones you mentioned, even with `fontspec`) and none worked.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - I wouldn't employ the `mathptmx` package here, since it provides both text and math Times Roman fonts and we don't need the math font part. Better to suggest a text-only Times Roman font package, such as `newtxtext`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to load `times` -- or, far better, `newtxtext` -- *before* rather than after `mtpro2`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
$\sin$ sin $s+i+n$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tested pdflatex English document with your code and it does work. However, I had to use `ctex` and xelatex because it is a Chinese document, in which case it still doesn't work.

Comment: @youthdoo - Is the `mtpro2` package known to work properly under XeLaTeX?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. I need to look at the manual/documentations.